# how to detect a cell in uicollectionview didselect delegate method

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am building an app similar to iPhone photo app. I am able to show the images in a grid like view using `PSUICollectionView`. When I tap on a grid cell of collection view a checkbox image should appear. My problem is when I am using following code, I see that multiple random cells are being populated with check box images.

```
- (void)collectionView:(PSUICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSLog(@"%@ - %d", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), indexPath.item);
    ImageGridCell *cell = (ImageGridCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton *chkboxBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [chkboxBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(60, 60, 30, 30)];
    [chkboxBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark-iPhone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:chkboxBtn];
}
```

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely your custom cell has not implemented the `prepareForReuse` method.  As a cell is reused, it may or may not have the check box, depending on if the check box was added on a previous use.

Several ways to address this.  One simple way is to add a tag to the `ckhboxBtn`, and then remove the `chkboxBton` in the `prepareForReuse` method.  E.g., when adding the check box, add the following:

```
[chkboxBtn setTag:100];
```

Then in your `UICollectionViewCell` class implementation, add/expand the `prepareForReuse` method:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse{
    [[self viewWithTag:100] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: does this also apply to UITableViewCells?

Comment: Yes it is now removing checkboxes from other random cells which was reused by uicollectionview. but the problem is that now check box was removed from even from the selected cells.

Comment: @SubhenduKumarMukherjee - you will need to keep track of which cells have been selected, and in the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` put the check box in place for those that have been selected.

Comment: @jhilgert00 - yes, `prepareForReuse` is applicable to `UITableViewCell`'s.  See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse